# How to tilt a texture on a sphere in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, textures

To teach myself Three.js, I am creating a simple solar system simulator. I have figured out how to get the planets to rotate on tilted axes using the `rotateOnAxis` function. The rotation looks funny though because the textures aren't tilted (i.e. Earth rotating on a 23 degree tilt, texture not tilted at all).

Is there any way I can tilt the texture 23 degrees so that the North Pole is pointing at an angle rather than straight up?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate your planet on an axis, you can use a pattern like this one:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

mesh.add( new THREE.AxisHelper( 10 ) ); // to show the local coordinate system

mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, - Math.PI * 23 / 180 ); // tilt
```

Then, in your render loop,

```
mesh.rotateY( 0.01 ); // rotate mesh around its local Y-axis
```

If your planet is textured, everything should look as expected.

three.js r.71

Answer (score 0):

Greate tutorial about this: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/09/16/how-to-make-the-earth-in-webgl/

P.S. Be careful - the image texture must be a power of two in height and width to tiled correctly.
P.P.S. This tutorial contains links to high-quality texture of the planets.

Comment: I read this one and it looks like all he does is change the `rotation.y` which doesnt change the angle of the axis.